# Firefox text opacity background issue

Tags: html, css, firefox, cross-browser

Take a look at this screenshot from Firefox:

[image]

The two left and right arrows are translucent text, at 20% and 80% opacity. The text has a text-shadow style applied. The images behind them also have varying opacities applied.

Other browsers are working fine - even IE6, in its own pathetic minimal way - but Firefox is drawing a strange black box behind the text. It's not filling the full text area, just the clip of the actual characters.

I know firefox is capable of doing transparency, so any idea what's triggering this strange behaviour?

---

**Update:** [here's a simple JSFiddle showing the effect](http://www.jsfiddle.net/sadie/A95L6/1/). Remove the `opacity` rule and the problem goes away.

I'm using Firefox 3.6.9 on Linux. The page uses jQuery and jQuery Tools for various opacity fading things, but as the fiddle above shows that isn't causing the issue.

Comment: Any chance of showing a live link or JSFiddle?

Comment: There you, updated with a fiddle.

Comment: I don't see any black box in the fiddle. Firefox 3.6.11 on Linux or 4.0b2 on Windows.

Comment: Then I guess it's only on the linux version, or only on version 3? Weird.

Comment: It doesn't even do it on a colleague's Firefox 3.6 on linux either. It really does appear to be just me. Ah well.

Comment: Let's blame graphics card drivers then.

Comment: Works fine on my 7.0.1 FF on Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

Instead of opacity have you tried background-color:rgba() ? You can control the opacity of the background color alone. You will still need to use opacity for IE

Comment: Just tried this, and rgba backgrounds seem to be ignored entirely?

Comment: are you sure you are using it correctly? background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.75) == black background color at .75 opacity

Answer (score 0):

For opacity issues:

http://davidwalsh.name/css-opacity

```
.show-50 { -moz-opacity:.50; filter:alpha(opacity=50); opacity:.50; }
```

Or perhaps better:

```
.show-50 {
-moz-opacity: 0.5 !important; 
-webkit-opacity: 0.5!important; -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)" !important; 
filter: alpha(opacity=50) !important;
opacity: 0.5 !important;}
```

Read more: http://www.robarspages.ca/web-development/css-opacity-for-all-browsers-cross-browser-compatible/#ixzz13MngpmvC

Comment: The problem isn't that the opacity isn't having an effect: as you can see in the picture, they really are faded out. The problem is that it injects a background inside the transparent element.